# button image gets pixelated

Tags: ios, iphone

I have designed a lock icon in Sketch to add to a button in my application:

[image]

I exported it both in pdf and png (2x, 3x) to add to Xcode assets. Problem is when I run the app on iPhone (SE), heavy pixelation can be seen around the edges of the icon:

[image]

I've tried both pdf and png formats, but result stays the same. Am I missing any settings that need to be applied for image to look sharp on screen?

Comment: can you please add the code of set image in button

Comment: I set it as background image in button’s attributes inspecot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bigger is not necessarily better for a `UIButton`'s image. Try to export your icon in more or less the same size with which it will be used. (Note that this also frees up memory in comparison to a way bigger image).

To adapt to different screens' resolutions, you should provide up to three images (@1x, @2x, @3x). You should read this excellent [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/) on **Image Size and Resolution**. It explains perfectly how big should the images you provide in Xcode be.

They also have a good explanation on which format you should use according to the purpose of the image.

EDIT:
 You can also use vector ressources (.pdf files for instance) that will  render perfectly for any resolution. You can read [this article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/xcode/how-to-use-vector-images-in-your-asset-catalog) about how to implement it in your Xcode project *(If you do so, please be careful in the attributes of the asset to check Preserve Vector Data and the Scales to Single Scale, otherwise it may not render well).*

Comment: That worked indeed. I’ve exported the image in roughly the biggest size it can get on 8 plus and it looks smooth and clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will happen if image sizes are not correct

*check the size of images. **1x,2x and 3x** sizes are should be as followed*

- **1x = 24x24 px**
- **2x = 48x48 px**
- **3x = 72x72 px**

If images size are too big than ImageView then pixelate will happen

***Hope this will help you***