# UIImageView gets pixelated

Tags: ios, swift

I need an image in two different sizes. 100px and 50px

I exported it with a height of 100px

While using the scaleAspectFit contentMode the smaller imageView gets pixelated.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553675/button-image-gets-pixelated) the solution would be to scale the image before importing it into the project. Since I need 2 different sizes I would prefer an alternative where I could only include the higher size and scale it down for the smaller imageView in order to keep the project size smaller. Is there any solution to achieve non pixelated images?

```
let templateImage = UIImage(named: exercise.imageName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageView.image = templateImage
    imageView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

[image: image1]
[image]

Comment: This sounds more like a project description rather than a question. Please show your code

Comment: Are you familiar with `@2x` and `@3x` concept for images import?

Comment: Generally scaling an image down works well and the results look good. Remember that almost all (all?) current iOS devices now have retina displays where a point is contains either 2x2 or 3x3 pixels. If you want to display an image in a 50 point by 50 point box, you should provide an image that's 100x100 pixels, and possibly also one that's 150x150 pixels for @3x retina displays.

Comment: You need edit your question to show your storyboard, including the settings for the image view, and also the details about the assets you are installing into the image view(s). Finally, if you do any setup for these images views you need to show that code.

Comment: @Scriptable updated the question

Comment: @DuncanC included the images, possibly the answer lies in the image set settings? i never considered these settings before

Comment: I tried importing it as a 50px image but then it doesn't look good on 100x100 ImageView and vice versa

Comment: What is the frame size (in ios points) of your UIImageView? What is the size of 1x, 2x and 3x images added to assets? You can select each of them and its size check in Attributes inspector

Comment: @lobstah ok so my UIImageView frame is equal to 30x30 and my 1x icon is 15x30 , my 2x icon is 30x60 and my 3x is 45x90

Comment: it is not clear, is it right that when you use those images ^ your image is pixelated?  Or is it pixelated if you use one image (of bigger size)?